# javassist used from jar loaded by some classloader

Tags: java, classloader, javassist

And I found issue, I should use only one simple `insertClassPath` instead of append, but it is still very buggy as it was able to find my class, but not use it when using append.

I'm creating addons/plugins for some Java app, that loads them from .jar files with own class loader (each addon have own classloader)

I want use javassist here but I can't create new class that will implement my interface and use my class.

Code:

```
final ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
pool.importPackage(Test.class.getPackage().getName());
pool.appendClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(this.getClass().getClassLoader()));
pool.appendClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(Test.class.getClassLoader()));
pool.appendClassPath(new ClassClassPath(Test.class));
final CtClass newClass = pool.makeClass("TeeestClass");
newClass.addInterface(pool.get(ObjectEvaluator.class.getName()));
// line of error:
newClass.addMethod(CtNewMethod.make(pool.get(Object.class.getName()), "eval", new CtClass[0], new CtClass[]{pool.get(Exception.class.getName())}, "{return new Test();}", newClass));
final Class<?> clazz = newClass.toClass(Test.class.getClassLoader());
//final Class<?> clazz = newClass.toClass(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
//final Class<?> clazz = newClass.toClass(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), this.getClass().getProtectionDomain());
final ObjectEvaluator obj = (ObjectEvaluator) clazz.newInstance();
System.out.println(obj.eval());
```

Where `Test` is my simple class with overridden `toString` method, and `ObjectEvaluator` is simple interface with `Object eval()` method.

(multiple `appendClassPath` are for testing/trying to make it work)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javassist.NotFoundException: myapp.Test
        at javassist.CtClassType.getClassFile2(CtClassType.java:208)
        at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupMethod(MemberResolver.java:99)
        at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupMethod(MemberResolver.java:85)
        at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMethodCallCore(TypeChecker.java:738)
        at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atNewExpr(TypeChecker.java:149)
        at javassist.compiler.ast.NewExpr.accept(NewExpr.java:73)
        at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:242)
        at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.compileExpr(CodeGen.java:229)
        at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atReturnStmnt2(CodeGen.java:615)
        at javassist.compiler.JvstCodeGen.atReturnStmnt(JvstCodeGen.java:425)
        at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:363)
        at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
        at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:351)
        at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
        at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atMethodBody(CodeGen.java:292)
        at javassist.compiler.Javac.compileBody(Javac.java:223)
        at javassist.CtBehavior.setBody(CtBehavior.java:438)
        at javassist.CtBehavior.setBody(CtBehavior.java:412)
        at javassist.CtNewMethod.make(CtNewMethod.java:138)
        at javassist.CtNewMethod.make(CtNewMethod.java:106)
        at myapp.Main.run(Main.java:60)
```

Comment: which line is line `60`? that will tell you what is wrong

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I marked it with`// line of error:`

Comment: And I found issue, I should use only one simple `insertClassPath` instead of append, but it is still very buggy as it was able to find my class, but not use it when using append.